# Get difference between two dates in days using ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I would like to know the time difference between two dates (`Time`/`DateTime` class) in days, i have one date created from the Date class and the other coming from my rails model, the one coming from the model is of the Time class, i want to know the number of days in between.

```
 @current_day = Date.new
 @created_day = establishment.created_at
```

i have tried getting this result using the `days_ago` function but it doesn't take into consideration the months.

Comment: You say that the dates are `Time` or `DateTime` objects, but your example contains strings. Furthermore, it is 23 days from the start date to the end date, not 22. Could you clarify that, please?

Comment: Let me edit the question

Answer (score 5):

```
old_date = Date.parse('2016-08-10')
new_date = Date.parse('2016-09-02')

days_between = (new_date - old_date).to_i
```

You have to convert days betweet to integer, because otherwise the result would be instance of Rational class.

Solution to your question after edit:

```
@current_day = Date.new
@created_day = establishment.created_at

days_between = (@current_day - @created_day.to_date).to_i
```

Comment: i get this error 'No implicit conversion of Date into String', im actually on rails i dont know if that might be the cause

Comment: This is pure Ruby solution. It does not matter if you are using Rails or any other framework. According to the error message, you are trying to convert instance of class Date to string. The code I suggested is working.

Answer (score -1):

Solution to your question: Try this one it will work.

days_between = ("Tue Oct 24 09:20:25 UTC 2017".to_date.."Fri Oct 27 11:20:08 UTC 2017".to_date).count

If you print the result(days_between) you will get result as 4